# With Scalaz streams, how can I evaluate a Process based on the contents of a previous Process?

Tags: scalaz-stream

I have a stream that will look something like:

A B A B A B A B A B A B ....

Where A and B are made up of one or more Process's. 
Based on the contents of a A, we want to do something with a B,
either passing it to a sink or drain.

I need to be able to make a decision about a B without evaluating it, as it maybe 
rather large  memory unfriendly - GBs

I am wondering if I need something similar to what is outlined in Eric's blog post:
http://etorreborre.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/streaming-with-previous-and-next.html

Comment: Are these A and B elements always interleaved like this?  Could you make this a stream of tuples, (A, B)?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as that would mean parsing the B, which I dont want to do.